# How to store multi-lingual website information in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, multilingual

I'm currently creating a multi-lingual website, and I have different types of words that are being translated all across the website. However, whats the best practice when it comes to storing this in the database?
This is what I currently do:

I have the language Norwegian and English.

**My database looks like this:**

[image: Language select]

Whenever I add a new language it get added into the `languages` table like this:

[image: Languages table]

At the same time a new table will be created with looking like this `language_en`. Using the value in `language_val`.

Later on I use URL routing to retrieve `en`, `no` or whatever language and fetch the website information from the correct table.

My question is, should I rather have only `1 table` and use the `language_id` in this one? or is it perfectly fine to split up languages into `multiple tables`?

**Each language table would look just like this:**
[image: language table]

Comment: Java would handle this as locale specific resource bundles.

Comment: @duffymo What about PHP?

Comment: Don't know; I don't write PHP. Did you tag your question?  Sorry I see that you did now. I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Silverlight (and later with PHP) I've done this by putting the language's in the same table, this worked fine and was user friendly (easy to edit). Only when retrieving data you should off course only select the language you need.

Comment: Is this faster than using separate tables? let's say I have 10 languages, each language has 1000 things to translate?

Comment: You should go for as few as possible tables in this case (normalization, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this will improve insight and makes your code more manageable aswell.